# How do I run the .scripts command? About the "Debugger for Chrome" of vscode extension

Tags: webpack, visual-studio-code, command-line, vscode-debugger

## What I tried

I ran the command as shown in the image below. However, the expected result was not obtained.
Can you tell me what's wrong?

[Execution screen screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QsdZz.png)

### console log

```
.scripts
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'
```

### Reference site

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=msjsdiag.debugger-for-chrome&ssr=false#overview

#### The .scripts command

> This feature is extremely useful for understanding how the extension maps files in your workspace to files running in Chrome. You can enter .scripts in the Debug Console to see a listing of all scripts loaded in the runtime, their sourcemap information, and how they are mapped to files on disk. The format is like this:

Answer (score 1):

Inside of VS Code you can set debug.javascript.usePreview: false. (Ctrl + ,). Make sure you set this to false for your workspace and you should be good to go.

Comment: I'm using vscode 1.61.0 and I don't see this setting, and when I add it to the JSON it shows upon hovering "Unknown Configuration Setting".  And the .scripts command doesn't work either.  Of course, I don't even have the [Debugger for Chrome](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=msjsdiag.debugger-for-chrome&ssr=false#overview) extension installed since it is deprecated and the functionality is part of the built-in [vscode-js-debug](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-js-debug/tree/v1.61.0#----------------) extension.  I'm going to ask that team if .scripts is still available.